# Android Firestore query collection group being skipped

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to grab subcollections using Firestore's `.collectionGroup` function however it doesn't seem to be firing at all. It should be returning at least one document found since its status is "Accepted" however when I run debug, it seems to skip over the function and doesn't return any kind of error or any of my logs.

When I run it normally, not in debug mode, it returns `"onComplete: found no book reservations for this book"`

I also was not prompted initially to create the composite index as is normally done with a singular index field when a new collection group query is first executed so I've attempted to make my own although I'm pretty sure it's not working correctly.

Any help or guidance is appreciated on how to solve this.

my firebase db setup is:
Collection:"Books"
-->subcollection:"bookPendingRequests"

[image]
[image]

[image]

here is a debug screen show to show that it is reading the correct bookFirebaseId
[image]

here is a markup of the firebase set up to illustrate what it should be reading. 
[image]

here is my collectionGroup index:
[image]

Here is my code which is set to start at onCreate()

```
private void loadBookReservationDates() {

        getIncomingIntent();

        bookPendingRequests = firestoreDB.collectionGroup("bookPendingRequests")
                .whereEqualTo("bookRequestParentId", bookFirebaseIdString)
                .whereEqualTo("bookReservationStatus", "Accepted");


        bookPendingRequests.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.getResult().size() < 0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < task.getResult().size(); i++) {
                        String dates = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(i).get("bookReservationDates").toString();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: dates: " + dates);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found no book reservations for this book");
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure() returned: " + e);
            }
        });

    }
```